# Show that the map $w(z)=\frac{1}{1-z^2}$ is a Conformal Mapping..

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, conformal-geometry

Show that the mapping $$w(z)=\frac{1}{1-z^2}$$ is a Conformal Mapping.

**My try-**

$$w(z)=\frac{1}{1-z^2}$$
$$ w'(z)=\frac{2z}{(1-z^2)^2}$$
$$ w'(z)\neq 0 \ \forall\  z\neq 0$$
So $w(z)$ is a Conformal Map for all $z\neq 0$
. What happens at $0, 1,-1$?

Comment: It is not defined at $1,-1$.  At $0$ it is defined, but not conformal.

Comment: @GEdgar Is it a mapping when z=0?

Comment: @GEdgar Please prove that w(z) is a well defined map.

Comment: When defining a map, you should state precisely what is the domain and what is the range of your map. (Before you start computing derivatives.) For instance, the formula that you wrote could be regarded as a map defined on the complex plane with the range equal to the Riemann sphere, or it could be interpreted in other ways.